# Is "e'er" a true English word?

Tags: contractions, is-it-a-word, poetry

Are poetic contractions, such as "e'er", "o'er" and "ne'er" (and other less common ones), English?  As in officially recognized?

Comment: If they are, then I've found the largest group of homophones ever!  Air, are, e'er, ere, err, eyre, and heir!  Hooray! Seven!

Comment: Are you saying that *are* sounds the same as *air* in your dialect?

Comment: It does in almost every dialect.  _Are_ as in "a surface measure equal to 100 square meters".

Comment: Never heard of that before!

Comment: Even those who've not hear "Are" befor may have heard "hectare"---that is 100 Are or the area of a square 100 meters on a side which is often used as a measure of agricultural land or the area of a political subdivision much like "acre" is used in the tradition system of English units.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what it means to be "officially recognized" in English; there is no official list of English words.

If you mean appearing in dictionaries, then [yes, it is a word](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/e%27er).

(If you mean being employed in speech or everyday writing without sounding odd, then probably not.  Its use is restricted to poetry, as you acknowledge.)

Comment: So I can use it in my homophone list?

Comment: @drm65: Well, why not?

Comment: I was afraid someone would say I was stretching English to get it.

Comment: @drm65: I guess, then, it depends on your intended audience.

Comment: @Kosmo: I'm trying to make a list, separating homophone pairs for a general audience from more obscure pairs, but keeping all I find.  I have over 1500 groups now, counting variant forms.

Comment: You wouldn't get away with **EER** in Scrabble (not if you were playing me, anyway! :)

Comment: How about [ELD, AVO, or KAE](http://phrontistery.info/scrabble3.html)?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, there are plenty of perfectly valid English words that aren't allowed in Scrabble. *Aren't*, for example.

Comment: @Martha: Doubtless we both agree that *perfectly, valid, English,* and *words* are all "words" - but like any two people, we probably disagree on exactly what they mean when strung together. My rule of thumb is - if it's in OSW it's definitely a word. If not, the burden of proof lies with whoever says it's a word. Me and OSW aren't minded to accept *aren't* as a word. :)

Answer (score 4):

These contractions are primarily relegated to literary usage nowadays, and such usage is sparing in modern literature.

There is one phrase, however, which enjoys continued popularity in the spoken vernacular:

> ne'er-do-well

Some might call it vestigial, but unlike the appendix, it still serves a useful purpose. No synonym carries the freight of implied prescience that this term bears.

"Wastrel" rolls deliciously on the tongue, and "good-for-nothing" judges those who are by present accounting utterly useless. But only "ne'er-do-well" pronounces "I have seen into your future, and there is no hope for you."

Scathing!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they're real abbreviated English words, though I wouldn't use them unless I wanted to sound old-fashioned or poetic.

What do you mean officially recognised? English has no official arbitrator other than your dictionary of choice; so just check in your favourite dictionary!

Comment: If we play our cards right, then in years to come EL&U will be recognised as the *official arbitrator*. And we'll all be such long-standing members we'll have the clout to just create and delete words at will! :)

Comment: @Fumblefingers, and we can excommunicate (exlinguate?) purveyors of poor grammar.  I think I'll start writing the list now...

Comment: @TimLymington: Do we dare start by exlinguating *Kosmonaut*, for suggesting in a comment that OP can consider **e'er** a valid word for a homophone list? No way am I going to play *him* at Scrabble without argument! :)